# Debugging lexical analyzer issue

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I am writing a lexical analyzer here is the code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
void showToken(char*);
%}

%%
int main(){
void showToken(char* name){
        printf("<%s,%s>",name,yytext);
}
return 0;
}
%%
```

I am getting the following :

```
~/hedor1>cc -c -o lexical.o lexical.c
lexical.l:40: error: expected identifier or â(â before â%â token
```

I cant find where is the problem and moreover in the CODE SECTION must I write :

```
int main(){}
```

what happens if I don't write the main function above?

Comment: You have a rule `[ \n]` that ignores blanks and newlines and a rule `{whitespace}+` that ignores blanks, tabs and newlines.  This is verging on redundant.

Comment: Looks like the question has been edited into nonsense?  Remove the code above and replace it with the ACTUAL code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Primary problem

You can only have two `%%` lines in a Lex (Flex) analyzer.

```
...definitions...
%%
...lexical patterns...
%%
...everything else...
```

The programs Lex and Flex simply copy the content of the file after the second `%%` verbatim into the generated C code.  And C doesn't like `%%` at any time.

#### Nitpick

You shouldn't nest functions inside each other like you're trying to with:

```
int main(){
void showToken(char* name){
        printf("<%s,%s>",name,yytext);
}
return 0;
}
```

You need to separate `main()` from `showToken()`.  (There is a GCC-specific extension that does allow nested functions.  Don't use it.)

---

Also, when you have a line number in an error message, it is helpful to insert a comment to identify the line in the source.  Or describe the line that is identified.  But we shouldn't have to count the lines in your code, even if the error is in line 1...well, maybe lines 1-3 aren't too critical, but there is a fuzzy breakpoint after which identifying the line is important.  By the time is has reached the teens, it is close to essential; the first 5 lines probably aren't crucial; in between (6-12) it's generally better to indicate the line number.

Comment: you have said to separate the function what will happen if I do not add the function main to my code? and what is the benefit of separation them this part is a C-code ?

Comment: The function `showToken()` can only be called from the `yylex()` function if it is visible; if the function `showToken()` is nested inside `main()`, it is only visible inside `main()` and cannot be the `showToken()` function called from `yylex()`.  If you don't add `main()`, then the Lex/Flex library (`-ll` or `-lfl`) will provide a dummy one: `int main(void) { while (yylex() > 0) ; }`.  You will almost certainly want to provide your own `main()` function.

Comment: so in my code if I remove the function main() will it work correctly, because I did not understand why the function yylex() needs to call my showtoken() function I call it just from the RULE SECTION by a simple c statements

Comment: The purpose of using Lex or Flex is to create a function `yylex()` that can be called to parse input.  The code in the patterns section is embedded into `yylex()` by Lex/Flex.  You have to provide the infrastructure to call `yylex()`, though the libraries do provide a bare minimal version of `main()`; they also provide a default `yywrap()`.  Your `yylex()` needs to call `showToken()` because the actions associated with your rules call it.  The pure generated code does not care a whit about `showToken()`, but your code embedded in there does.